# exec.Command("date") not able to find date command

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    out, err := exec.Command("date").Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("The date is %s\n", out)
}
```

This is a code example from the documentation for executing system commands. http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#example_Cmd_Output Even on the documentation site the example execute box doesn't run and has the same error:
**2009/11/10 23:00:00 exec: "date": executable file not found in $PATH**

On Windows I get:
exec: "date": executable file not found in %PATH%

How do I get commands to work? Do I need to set a path or write out the full path of the command?

Comment: If you open up a terminal and run `date`, does it work?

Comment: Yes. I get 25 October 2013 01:48:31.

Comment: Try running `which date`, then replacing `date` in your code with the fully qualified path of the `date` executable. (I realize this isn't what you want long-term, I'm just trying to diagnose.)

Comment: Using the Get-Command to find the path, I tried `Get-Command ping` and it returned the path, `Get-Command ipconfig` did too, yet the `Get-Command date` says "The term 'date' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet". Edit: using `where`, I get the same result.

Comment: On Windows 'date' is built into the command processor, so its not an executable that you are able to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, that example isn't going to work for you unless you get a `date.exe` from somewhere (Cygwin?) and put in on your `%PATH%`.

What's going on, I believe, is that `date` is a builtin in Powershell. It works for you because your shell is interpreting it.

You may be able to do

```
out, err := exec.Command("cmd", "/C", "date").Output()
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008255/how-to-execute-a-simple-windows-dos-command-in-golang); I don't know, I don't have a Windows machine handy.

---

Sidenote:

> Get-Command date says "The term 'date' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"

There are exactly two Google results for that phrase. One of them leads me to [this](http://powershell.cz/2012/12/07/last-modified-date-brainteaser/), which helped me figure this out.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 2):

On windows since date is not a executable, I changed your code to run as follows:

```
out, err := exec.Command("cmd.exe", " /c date /t").Output()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("The date is %s\n", out)
```

The output:

```
The date is Fri 25/10/2013
```