# How to stop Golang from replacing double-quotes with backslashes when executing a Windows command?

Tags: windows, go, cmd, double-quotes, backslash

I am writing a program in Golang that will use Mozilla's Thunderbird email client to send email. The Windows command that should be executed is:

```
 start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe" -compose "to='CloudCoin@Protonmail.com',subject='Subject1',body='Hello'" -offline
```

My Go code looks like this (command is the one listed above) :

```
    var command string
    command = `start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe"`
    command += ` -compose "to='` + toAddress + `',`
    command += `subject='Subject1',`
    command += `body='Hello'"`
    command += ` -offline`

    cmd := exec.Command("cmd.exe", "/C", command)
```

But I get an error:

```
Windows cannot find '\\'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.
```

If I change the code to this (moving the word start):

```
    var command string
    command = ` "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe"`
    command += ` -compose "to='` + toAddress + `',`
    command += `subject='Subject1',`
    command += `body='Hello'"`
    command += ` -offline`

    fmt.Println("Command: " + command)

    cmd := exec.Command("cmd.exe", "/C", "start", command)
```

Then I get another error:

```
Windows cannot find 'Files'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.
```

It seems that instead of trying to start "" it is trying to start \\. How can I keep my double-quotes?

Comment: Can we see how you are declaring "command".

Comment: Totally wrong as unnecessary quoting. Thats all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem likely is that every separate string passed to `exec.Command` is passed on (without parsing it) as a single argument to `cmd.exe`, which does probably not split given strings either, so you have to do it yourself.

See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13013520/6266540) where the argument is being split up too. You should be able to leave " out since you split it up manually anyway, or write a program for it or run it with an interpreter which does the splitting.

```
func do() {
    args := []string{
        "/C",
        "start",
        "",
        `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe`,
        "-compose",
        "to=" + toAddress + ",subject=Subject1,body=Hello",
        "-offline",
    }
    cmd := exec.Command("cmd.exe", args...)
}
```